# Defining a unique constraint on Django CMSPlugin field in a multilingual site

Tags: django, django-cms

I have a field `title` in a model `Skill` inheriting from `CMSPlugin`. I am using the following properties of my `Skill` objects as a unique identifier:

- `title`
- `language`
- `placeholder.page.publisher_is_draft` (weather the corresponding page is published or draft)

I would like to prevent users from creating two instances where these three properties are equal. It seems I cannot achieve this with a `unique_together` definition, as the third property is not part of the model. Is there a **built-in** mechanism in the Django CMS to define such a constraint?

Comment: I don't think you can do this at the db level, I think adding clean() to your model or form where you validate this uniqueness, should solve the problem

Comment: Thanks! That sounds reasonable, and no one had a better idea. If you want your 25 reputation, post this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure thing, this is what I gathered from your question.

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class MyPlugin(CMSPlugin):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    is_draft = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def clean(self):
        manager = self.__class__.objects
        self.is_draft = self.placeholder.page.publisher_is_draft
        if manager.filter(title=self.title, language=self.language, is_draft=self.is_draft).exists():
            raise ValidationError("Duplicate !!!")
```